# How to manage multiple f-curve modifiers

Tags: animation

I have more than 30 bones animated and each of them needs the "cycles" f-curve-modifier to continue animating up until frame 100.

Is there any way to change all these modifiers simultaneously, or do I need to go trough each modifier separately in order to change their end frames?

Comment: Did I make some mismatch here? I put a picture into a related but different question !

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Not sure what you are doing here, can you find the posts and ping a moderator in our chatroom.

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Were you looking for your post [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38695/599)?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you should be able to apply the modifier to one curve, copy it, select all of the curves, and then paste.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of the relevant parts?

Comment: the hammer in the foreground is the original one, i made the curve in the graph editor, than I duplicated this hammer. So I have two hammer that shares one curve. I would like to change the curve only for the second hammer.