# How to add extrapolation functionality in Blender 2.69?

Tags: graph-editor

[image]

I saw this short tutorial on youtube, 
someone made a rotation animation of two keyframes, opened the graph editor, changed the interpolation mode to linear and selected linear extrapolation. The effect was, that although he animated a limited rotation, the extrapolatiton made the rotation infinite in both directions.

I tried to make this with my Blender (version 2.69), but as I opened the Key-window inside the graph editor there was no Extrapolation mode to select, only interpolation mode.

Do I have to add this mode separetly or is there another way to create this infinite rotation ?

Comment: Update to a newer version of blender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.69 this was in the *Channel* menu (<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>):

[image]

However I recommend updating to the latest version (2.75). See [Is it advisable to update Blender to the newest version as soon as possible each time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6744/599)

Comment: great, why did they put the extrapolation mode function into another context menu? I am not sure how to update blender, I installed it in linux only one week ago by typing into the console: sudo apt-get install blender , and assumed it would install the newest version by default.

Comment: The packages available for linux distributions are not always updated to newest versions, sometimes you need to use a [custom ppa](http://askubuntu.com/a/585266/183698) from a user that builds updated blender versions for themselves. You don't have to use the Shift-E context menu - it is in the channel menu, it was moved from the key menu to the channel menu in 2.56 so the tutorial was made before that.